# Вылезла ошибка в codelite на linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, codelite

**выходит при компиляции проекта в codelite**(ubuntu 18.04) 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Создай run.py и запиши туда:

```
import os

print("Compilation...")

os.system("g++ main.cpp -o Program -lpthread")

print("Press <Enter> to start program...")

input()

os.system("clear")

os.system("./Program")
```

разместите этот файл рядом с main.cpp. Если у вас много файлов .cpp/.c, то просто добавляете их вот так: `os.system("g++ main.cpp file2.cpp Player.cpp -o Program -lpthread")`

потом просто запускаете это вот так: `python3 run.py`, у вас компилируется программа и запускается

Comment: Очень советую выбрать python как второй язык, я лично тоже очень люблю c++ и это мой первый, основной и любимый язык, но python тоже очень полезен иногда

Comment: написал а как добавить в codelite?

Comment: зачем? ты можешь там писать, а компилировать в терминале.

+юзай не codelite, а atom или Visual Code

Comment: понимаешь я решаю олимпиады и у меня много разных  задач и мне не удобно каждый раз приписывать файл

Comment: стрелачку вверх нажимай....

Comment: хорошо а дебаг?

Comment: никогда этого не делал... Но знаю что вроде в Visual Code есть дебаг c++ в каком-то плагине

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102502/discussion-between-samyrai-and-lofectr).